# Complex ArcGIS Server Infra problem

Tags: arcgis-server, classextensions

We have a large application running on Java, RHEL, where our ArcGIS Server resides also.

We have a lot of inteligence on some of our classes and we wish to publish them via arcgis server. The problem is, that being RHEL I cannot just register the class extension dlls in it and when AGS tries to initialize them, it fails.

I don't need the class extensions to work via web, I just need to be able to show them up on a map (no editions will be made). Is there any viable solution that does not involve:

A) recoding;
B) switching to a different environment;

Can I figure out a way of skipping the initialization of the class extension on the server?

EDIT:

Since I don't need the complex edit behavior we have in ArcGIS Desktop, I'm gonna try to fool AGS. I'm going to build the same class extension as we have on the .NET side, but with Java, without behavior and deploy it to the ags.

Answer (score 2):

Hy,
could you describe your class extensions? What are they making?

Without further details, I would suggest to recode your extension in Java.
The ArcObjects are very close between Java and .Net. The work should be very small as you already did it in .Net.

If you want to reuse your dll's, you should have to move the ArcSOC's to the windows. But I think this workaround will not work in 10.1.

Tom

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for the answer. My class extensions performs extensive validation and feature completion (I create other features while the user edits in ArcMap).The idea, which it failed, was to create an empty featureclass in Java with the same name as my original .NET class extension. My guess is, how AGS looks up for each class extension? By class name? Or by GUID? If by GUID, how do I specify it in Java? In the documents they did not say.

Comment: "The ArcObjects are very close between Java and .Net" ...and here's hoping your .NET work is in C# instead of VB! @George the class extension is registered to a feature class with its GUID (though I don't know how to specify a class GUID in Java). http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AlterClassExtensionCLSID_Method/0025000000v4000000/

Comment: Hi Tom! My work is all in C# and could not found a way to specify the GUID in Java. Besides that, it should've work.